# Error Python concatenacion sin resolver

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola soy nuevo en programación en [python](/questions/tagged/python) y estoy generando un código en el cual hago una conexión a una base de datos en [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) el código es el siguiente:

```
#! / usr / bin / python
# - * - coding: UTF-8 - * -
import os, sys
import signal, os, sys
import MySQLdb
conexion_mysql = MySQLdb.connect(host = '10.248.204.43', user = 'root', passwd = 'sahc', db = 'Biblioteca')

cur = conexion_mysql.cursor()
consulta = ('SELECT *, IF(time >= 10,"Bad","Good") AS Estado FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE id <> connection_id()')
cur.execute(consulta)
for row in cur.fetchall():
    resultado = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8]
    print resultado
    sql = "INSERT INTO prueba VALUES (" + str(row[0]) + "," + "'" + row[1] + "'" + "," + "'" + row[2] + "'" + "," + "'" + row[3] + "'" + "," + "'" + row[4] + "'" + "," + str(row[5]) + "," + "'" + row[6] + "'" + "," + "'" + row[7] + "'" + "," + "now()" + ")"
    cur.execute(sql)
    conexion_mysql.commit()
```

Como se ve en el codigo anterior estoy conectado a una base de datos local haciendo una consulta a una tabla por defecto de MySQL y cuando la consulta cumple con las condiciones las mando a insertar a una tabla de la base de datos local, la consulta como tal me arroja los resultado como quiero pero no me deja insertarlos por el siguiente codigo de error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shuh/PycharmProjects/prueba/MataViejitos", line 14, in <module>
    sql = "INSERT INTO prueba VALUES (" + str(row[0]) + "," + "'" + row[1] + "'" + "," + "'" + row[2] + "'" + "," + "'" + row[3] + "'" + "," + "'" + row[4] + "'" + "," + str(row[5]) + "," + "'" + row[6] + "'" + "," + "'" + row[7] + "'" + "," + "now()" + ")"
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Ya chequee los campos de los resultados con los row y no hay nada que me indique que no se pueda concatenar, los resultado que me arroja la consulta es la siguiente:

```
(10L, 'root', 'xcsisctxsoporte.grupoxcaret.com:54413', None, 'Sleep', 2L, '', None, 'Good')
(9L, 'root', 'xcsisctxsoporte.grupoxcaret.com:54412', None, 'Sleep', 1956L, '', None, 'Bad')
(5L, 'root', 'xcsisctxsoporte.grupoxcaret.com:54408', None, 'Sleep', 372L, '', None, 'Bad')
(6L, 'yuli', 'localhost', 'Biblioteca', 'Sleep', 1968L, '', None, 'Bad')
(4L, 'root', 'xcsisctxsoporte.grupoxcaret.com:54407', None, 'Sleep', 372L, '', None, 'Bad')
```

Comment: ¿Por qué concatenas `None` con un `str`?

Comment: Pues la verdad ya intente quitandole el str() y aun asi me marca el mismo error ya verifique los campos del resultado con el insertado y ya modifique pero aun asi me sale el mismo error :(

Comment: No es eso, fijate en el resultado del `print` que haces, hay valores `None`, debes confirmar que esos valores son distintos antes de intentar utilizarlos.

Comment: Intenta usando `(row[x] or '')` de tal manera que los que sean `None` se conviertan a `''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa `(row[x] or '')` de tal manera que los que sean `None` se conviertan a `''`.

Answer (score 2):

El comentario de @César es el correcto :)

> Intenta usando (row[x] or '') de tal manera que los que sean None se conviertan a ''